# polyglossia and \selectlanguage in the preamble causing Chinese characters disappear

Tags: polyglossia, cjk, ctex

Consider the following example (compile with `xelatex`):

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctex}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[frenchpart=false]{french}

\selectlanguage{french}                         % Doesn't work
% \AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{french}}     % Doesn't work

\begin{document}

% \selectlanguage{french}                       % Works

你好

\end{document}
```

With `\selectlanguage{french}` in the preamble, Chinese characters `你好` disappear. Even if I add `\AtBeginDocument` to it, the characters are still missing. However it works fine if I use `\selectlanguage{french}` within the document.

This only occurs with `polyglossia`. `babel` doesn't have this problem.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

polyglossia selects the default language after \begin{document} (in the `begindocument/end` hook).

In your this language is english. If you select `french` before this point, selecting the english language will also execute `\noextras@french` which beside others contains also  `\nofrench@punctuation` and this changes `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` to 0.

You would get a similar problem inside the document with

```
\selectlanguage{french}                      
\selectlanguage{english}
你好
```

I would say this is a polyglossia bug, it shouldn't assume that quitting french means that you no longer want to use `\XeTeXintercharclasses`.

You can disable this with

```
\makeatletter
\gappto\noextras@french{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1\relax}
\makeatother
```

(There is probably a way without the`@` but `\noextrasfrench` doesn't work).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Also, I'm confused, why is `\AtBeginDocument{...}` different with just writing `...` after `\begin{document}`? It does work if I change `\AtBeginDocument` with `\AfterEndPreamble` provided by `etoolbox`.

Comment: you should trust me that I try these things. So it worked for me.  polyglossia sets the the language in the begindocument/end hook (which is the same as \AfterEndPreamble), so you are too early in \AtBeginDocument. But using \AfterEndPreamble will only help in your small example, in larger documents with more language changes it will break again.

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried again and find that it does work. Perhaps I made some mistakes before :-p

Comment: I found that this issue also happens with `lualatex`, is there such a macro like `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` in this case? `\luaTeXinterchartokenstate` nor `\LuaTeXinterchartokenstate` does not exist.

Comment: no, luatex is different and I can't reproduce the problem there, (I have to use \usepackage[fontset=fandol]{ctex} there, so can't test exactly the same example).