# The use of polyglossia changes Chinese font selection

Tags: polyglossia, ctex

I just switched from `babel` to `polyglossia`, and surprisingly found my san-serif Chinese font changes. Consider the following example:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{ctex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
你好

\end{document}
```

The sans-serif font for Chinese has been reset to the main font (English font doesn't get affected).

It would be fine without `polyglossia`, so I wonder what is inside `polyglossia` that  leads to this behavior?

(This, together with [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586304/194994), shows that `polyglossia` currently interacting somewhat badly with Chinese language. Thus, at least for now, I shall follow the suggestion of @UlrikeFischer, consider switching back to the more stable `babel`.)

Comment: Why do you switch to polyglossia?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is because (to my experience) documents using polyglossia compile slightly faster than those using babel. And many posts on this site seem to suggest using polyglossia with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Well you found directly two problems in polyglossia so you should perhaps reconsider your decision. And the french module in babel is certainly better than the polyglossia one. I always use babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\sffamily` command has a hook, this hook is used by ctex to inject the font changes it needs.

`polyglossia` redefines `\sffamily` and so detroys this hook.

This has been already reported: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/471